# What does it mean by gpg encrypting a file with multiple recipients?

Tags: encryption, gpg

To encrypt a file using a person's public key, I can use the following command.

```
gpg --recipient anonymous@anonymous.io --encrypt --armor file_name
```

I don't quite understand when this command has multiple `--recipient` parameters. Below is an example.

```
gpg --recipient anonymous@anonymous.io --recipient x@x.x --encrypt --armor file_name
```

This command only generates a single encrypted file called `file_name.asc`. In this case, does it mean `file_name.asc` can be decrypted by both user's corresponding private key? Could anyone help to explain when we need multiple `--recipient` parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In this case, does it mean `file_name.asc` can be decrypted by both user's corresponding private key?

Yes, any of the recipient keys will be able to decrypt the message. Strictly speaking, the message is encrypted using a common key, and that key is encrypted using each provided public key. Thus any of the corresponding private keys can decrypt the common key and then the message.

> Could anyone help to explain when we need multiple `--recipient` parameters?

A common scenario is for email encrypted to multiple recipients. Another is storing encrypted content accessible to multiple users without any shared key.